# Парсинг сайта лото, проблема с получением информации

Tags: python, парсер

Есть страница с сайта https://www.lotto.pl/lotto/wyniki-i-wygrane/date,2020-08-30,1 за конкретную дату.
На странице по умолчанию отображаются результаты в отсортированном виде, хотя если нажать на кнопке "Sortuj liczby wg kolejności losowania" цифры отображаются в порядке выпадения.

При анализе страницы (Ctrl+U) данные только в отсортированном виде. Инструмент разработчика Network не отображает переход для получения данных, кроме как отсылает на facebook, но там пусто.
Другие инструменты тоже не дали результата.

Может кто-нибудь может подсказать в каком скрипте данные находятся в порядке выпадения или идею куда "копать".

Comment: На всех нормальных системах есть REST API. Зачем вы так мучаетесь? Воспользуйтесь нормальным подходом.

Comment: https://www.wykop.pl/wpis/24530013/lotto-programowanie-api-wie-ktos-czy-istnieje-dost/

Comment: https://forum.multipasko.pl/5516 и так далее. Гуглите и обрящете.

Comment: Тут вообще CSV/XLS разддают. http://www.mbnet.com.pl/wyniki.htm